# Where can I store a Bitcoin Wallet Safely?

Tags: wallet, security, backup

I am a newbie and I would like to know where can I create/store my Bitcoin Wallet safely. I have downloaded the Bitcoin software but storing it in my local computer seem like a high risk, but also is trusting a third-party.

How do you guys do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an in-depth article that explains the steps you should take to secure your wallet. https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Securing_your_wallet.